# Uploading to github process

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch

I do the following steps to upload my projects to github, which I think is not the best practice.
I do these steps at every projects.

1. Create github repo with readme file
2. Delete readme file on github page
3. git init on PC
4. git remote add origin *githubrepourl*
5. git fetch
6. git checkout main
7. git add .
8. git commit -m "Init"
9. git push origin main

The reason to create and also delete the readme file on 1. and 2. steps is that:
I tried the whole steps without creating the readme file and when I tried sync the 2 repo (local and remote) the git gave me error

The reason to checkout main: The default branch on local git (the git software) is "master".

If I would not checkout the main and if I would upload the the content on github then there would be 2 branch: main and master and the project content would be in master which I don't want to be, because when someone would visit my github repo page on github then it would be an empty site, because on github page the default branch is 'main' which would be empty.

So thats the reason why I change to main at the beginning, which is github default branch.

Comment: Why don't you configure a consistent default branch name?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean configuring a default branch name on local? Changing master to main? Can I do that? How can I do that? ( Why not comes the Git software with the same default branch name as github ? ... )

Comment: At either end. You can look up how to do either.

Comment: Note that you need a fairly recent Git version to *configure* a default initial branch name; with a slightly older one you can run `git init --initial-branch=main`. If you cannot upgrade, you can just run `git init` locally, create your initial commit locally, then run `git branch -m main` to rename the current branch name—whatever it may be—to become `main`, or run `git init` and then `git checkout --orphan main`, which works even with the ancient Git 1.8 that's still shipped in some systems.

Comment: As for why GitHub and Git drifted apart here, it's because GitHub is full of activists and Git is very traditionalist.  Whether you agree with them or not, GitHub simply moved first here.

Comment: @torek I have git version 2.35.1 . What do you suggest, do I need at the start using `git init --initial-branch=main` ??

Comment: 2.35 has the configuration knob: `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` and from then on `git init` will set you up to have `main` in a new empty repository that it creates (remember that `git init` on an *existing* repository basically does nothing, so this is only for *new* ones).

Comment: @torek Thank you. Btw whats the benefit setting the user.email and user.name? I ask this because git does not let me commit without i set these AND user.email and user.name does not connected to github, I mean user.email != *Email I use to login github* .  So what is the benefit using user.email and user.name? Thank you.

Comment: Every time you make a *new* commit, Git allocates a new, unique hash ID (that can never be used again) and writes out a full snapshot all your files, along with some metadata describing the commit you just made. In that metadata, Git records your `user.name` and `user.email` settings and the current date-and-time from your computer clock, plus the log message you specify. You can use these later to see what you did, when. Git requires that all commits include this metadata, but does not verify that you're telling the truth (it literally *can't* do that).

Comment: Other services like GitHub *can*, if they choose, inspect your authentication and the new commits you're sending them and *verify* the name and email address. GitHub (generally, maybe there's some specific mode I'm not aware of) do not do this but some other hosting sites *do* do that.

Comment: The new commits you make—the new snapshots with metadata—are completely frozen for all time, and use up that hash ID that Git picks apparently randomly (but not actually random at all). That hash ID *means* **that particular commit** in *every* Git repository now and forever.

Comment: Note that the commits, with their hash IDs, are permanent and unchanging. The branch names you choose are up to you and are *not* permanent and can be changed any time, and nobody else has to use the same name(s) you're using. It's the commits and their hash IDs that matter, not the branch names. But human brains are too feeble to work with hash IDs: that's why we like (and use) names instead. The names help us (and Git) *find* our commits, and we remember the names and Git remembers hash IDs using those names.

Comment: @torek Thank you! Can you help me why my 2 name (github username and commit name) does not match? (NAME 1 vs NAME 2) . I tried to change NAME 2 with user.email and user.name , but user.email and user.name does not affect NAME 2 . So where does NAME 2 come from?
https://unsee.cc/album#NGyLXJzHymIlCUJu

Comment: First check (with `git log --pretty=fuller`) that both the author and committer of each commit is the `user.name` and `user.email` that you want. If so, concentrate on *how* you send commits *to* GitHub: is it via https, or via ssh? If https, how do you authenticate: which credential manager(s) do you use and what do they send for user name and password ("token" on GitHub, but a token *is* a password, its just a structured one). If it's ssh, what key-pair do you use? When you registered the public key with GitHub, what user name did you tell GitHub this public key goes with?

Comment: If `git log --pretty=fuller` shows that you're using two different names for author and committer, this is because you're using one of the Git commands that *copies* an *existing* commit while preserving the old author name (your user.name etc become the new committer). Consider adding `--reset-author` or whatever flag is appropriate here to make Git also change the author name.